# Is it possible to set version constraints for git packages in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, dart-packages

Our project structure is look like below:

```
(b5df1cc)
common    -> package1 \
                       \
(56e0bc0)               \
common    -> package2 -----> myApp
                        /
(101aa16)              /
common    -> package3 /
```

`myApp` dependent on `package1`, `pacakge2`, `package3`, and `package1`, `pacakge2`, `pacakge3` dependent on `common` package([git packages](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages)), but the `common` package(git packages) may have different commit hash. After run `flutter packages get`, it will show the error like:

```
Because every version of package1 from git depends on common from git {url: git@bitbucket.org:common.git, ref: b5df1cc, path: common} and every version of package2 from git depends on common from git {url: git@bitbucket.org:common.git, ref: 56e0bc0, path: common}, package1 from git is incompatible with package2 from git.
So, because myApp depends on both package2 from git and package1 from git, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in myApp...
pub get failed (1; So, because myApp depends on both package2 from git and package1 from git, version solving failed.)
```

Is it possible to set the version constraints or other way to ignore the "version solving failed" error for git packages? Because we can ensure that all the code from `common` package(git package) is compatible with `pacakge1`, `package2`, `package3`, if it can set the version constraints, like `>=2.0.0 <3.0.0`, we can let the version never reach `3.0.0`, so `myApp` can compatible with `package1`, `pacakge2`, `package3`, etc.

**Updated:**

Use [dependency_override](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) can solve this problem, but the `dependency_override` need to be set in the `myApp`, when the common package is updated, we need to update the common package in `myApp` at the same time, say if I update the common package in `package1`, I need to update the common package in `myApp` too, which is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is using [dependency_overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides)

Note: it might break package1/2/3 as it forces to use them some version of common package, ignoring their constraints

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible to use `dependency_override`, but when the common package is updated, we need to update the common package in `myApp`  at the same time, say if I update the common package in `package1`, I need to update the common package in `myApp` too.

Comment: Anyway your app uses only one single version of common package at the moment of time

Comment: You should consider hosting a private pub.dev or using SaaS like cloudsmith.io

Comment: @TheVinhLuong is there any guide about hosting a private pub.dev?

Comment: @Pavel Yes, you can look into it here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/blob/master/doc/development.md